# Setup for sub-captions for two sub-figures one below the other

Tags: spacing, subfloats, subcaption

I am using the caption and subcaption packages to create sub-figures in a document.  I have two cases of sub-figures:

1. Two sub-figures side-by-side.  For this, the captioning is excellent.
2. Two sub-figures one below the other. in this case, the first sub-caption appears immediately above the second sub-figure.

How can I configure the sub-captions to include a small space between themselves and the next element in the second case, without messing up the setup for the first case?

The rude way is to stick a vskip explicitly after the first sub-figure.  I prefer to avoid this hack.

Comment: I do not think that `\vskip` is a hack. You want vertical space and that is what `\vskip` gives you. If you want to separate content from presentation, you can define your own macros, say `\horiontalsubfigures[caption1][caption2]{figure1}{figure2}` and `\verticalsubfigures[caption1][caption2]{figure1}{figure2}` and use `\hskip` and `\vskip` in the macro definitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the length `\belowcaptionskip` (default value 0pt) as you need it. Either do this locally inside the concerned figure environment as shown below or globally in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{5pt}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.75\textwidth}
      \rule{\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}
      \caption{First sub-figure}\label{fig:first}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.75\textwidth}
      \rule{\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}
      \caption{Second sub-figure}\label{fig:second}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two dummy sub-figures}\label{dummy}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The [caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) manual has the details.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, but this solution doesn't work for me. Setting `\belowcaptionskip` adds space after the caption for the whole figure (which I don't want), rather than under the subfigure captions (which is what I do want). Any ideas?

Comment: @Roly: Move the line with `\setlength` into the first `subfigure` environment (or insert it in both).

Comment: Thanks. Actually I had already tried that. Unfortuately, inside the `subfigure` environment `\setlength` does nothing for my document. (Moved back to the `figure` environment it affects only the spacing after the caption of the whole figure.) I'll have to come up with a MWE.