# Align 9 figures with labels on the right and bottom

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats, labels, subcaption

I'm trying to have 9 sub-figures under a single figure.
I would like for it to look something like :
[image]

Would appreciate any help in this regard!
(Kindly mention the necessary packages as required as well)

Comment: Welcome to the site :) perhaps start with `subfigure` from `subcaption` package. sample: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5685/setup-for-sub-captions-for-two-sub-figures-one-below-the-other?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can arrange the content in a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tabular}{ r c c c l }
    \phantom{Dataset~1} &
      \includegraphics[valign=c,height=40pt]{example-image-a} &
      \includegraphics[valign=c,height=40pt]{example-image-b} &
      \includegraphics[valign=c,height=40pt]{example-image-c} &
      Dataset~1 \\ \\[\medskipamount]
    \phantom{Dataset~2} &
      \includegraphics[valign=c,height=40pt]{example-image-b} &
      \includegraphics[valign=c,height=40pt]{example-image-c} &
      \includegraphics[valign=c,height=40pt]{example-image-a} &
      Dataset~2 \\ \\[\medskipamount]
    \phantom{Dataset~3} &
      \includegraphics[valign=c,height=40pt]{example-image-c} &
      \includegraphics[valign=c,height=40pt]{example-image-a} &
      \includegraphics[valign=c,height=40pt]{example-image-b} &
      Dataset~3 \\ \\[\smallskipamount]
    & (a)~curve~$x$ &
      (b)~curve~$y$ &
      (c)~curve~$z$
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{The $x$, $y$ and~$z$ curves of the three datasets.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

A complementary `r` first column (with duplicated `\phantom` content) is inserted to center the image configuration.

Comment: This works beautifully! Thanks :)

Comment: the margins in between the figures are slightly more than what I require. Is there any alternative using subfigures?

Comment: @JoshithaR: The *gaps* between the figures are give by the length `\tabcolsep`. You can adjust those. Add `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.5\tabcolsep}` to the figure environment before the `tabular` to cut them in half. Or set something explicit, like `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}`.